# Can I get steam redeem key for my Civilization 5 purchase on Apple AppStore?

Tags: steam, civilization-5

A few months ago I bought Civilization 5 on AppStore but since then I'm using only Steam for all purchases.
I've noticed that for example on Humble Bundle you can directly download the game or get Steam redeem keys.

So I was wondering if I can get Steam redeem key also for Civilization 5 that I bought on AppStore.

Comment: Hmm, on Windows Civ5 uses SteamWorks, which means all copies are Steam, regardless of place of purchase.  Don't know how that works on a Mac, though.

Comment: Agreed with the duplicate report. Check the link in the above comment for an answer (in short, it appears to be a resounding *no*).